# /etc/bash.bashrc invoked incorectly on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bash, ubuntu, bugs

Using a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 I have found that the --rcfile option is not working as documented.

From the man bash  page:

> The --rcfile file option will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.

However when I add to /etc/bash.bashrc an echo statement at the top like `echo Inside bash.bashrc` and then execute:

```
/bin/bash --rcfile /tmp/some_test -i
```

where /tmp/some_test has some simple alias command or otherwise I get output as follows:

```
Inside bash.bashrc
you are in /tmp/some_test right now
```

This seems to be a bug since the --rcfile should have ignored the /etc/bash.bashrc file.

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Sounds like this needs to be filed as a bug instead of a question on U&L?

Comment: My man page for `bash` differs from yours.  Mine says of the `--rcfile file` option: _Execute commands from file instead of the standard personal initialization file ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive (see INVOCATION below)._  That seems to line up with the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Have you cleaned out the shell from you run the tests? Inheritance!